# Preservation of concavity by an integral equation

Tags: integration, convex-analysis

CONTEXT:
In the research problem I am currently investigating, I have come across an integral equation of the form
$
u(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\,K(x,y)v(y)\,dy,
$
where I know the following information about the function $v$ on $[0,\infty)$: it is positive, uniformly continuous, strictly increasing, concave down, bounded by $A$, and $v(0)=0$. The properties of the integration kernel $K$ are such that (e.g. total positivity, boundedness,...) I can conclude that the function $u$ defined in the integral equation above is also positive, uniformly continuous, bounded and strictly increasing with $u(0)=0$.  I am interested in the concavity properties of $u$.

Unfortunately, the total positivity class of the kernel does not allow me to immediately directly conclude that $u$ is concave down in general, so I need another argument.

END CONXTEXT

I know that further to the above assumptions on $v$, if I assume that $v$ is of the form $v(y)=y\cdot h(y)$ where $h$ is continuous, positive, bounded, decreasing and concave up, then $u$ in the above integral equation is also of the form $u(x)=x\cdot g(x)$, where $g$ is continuous, positive, bounded, decreasing and concave up.

My question then is as follows: with these extra assumptions, does it follow that $u$ is concave down?  This appears to me a question that should be independent of the fact that $u$ is expressed in terms of an integral as above; it should be solvable using just basic calculus, and posed as follows:

Assume $u$ is a positive, bounded, uniformly continuous, strictly increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ with $u(0)=0$.  Further assume that $u(x)=x\cdot g(x)$ where $g$ is continuous, positive, decreasing, bounded and concave up.  Does it follow that $u$ is concave down?  I would be happy with a solution that would further assume smoothness of all the functions involved so that the question could be reduced to proving (given $0\leq u(x)\leq A$, $0\leq g(x)\leq B$, $u'(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)>0$, $g'(x)<0$, $g''(x)>0$) that $u''(x)=2g'(x)+xg''(x) < 0$ on $[0,\infty)$.